# how do i select the first 4 columns from my CSV file and run a query

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, csv, datagridview, datatable

I have a method and I want to query the 3rd column in my CSV file BUT I want to only display the first four columns. I am hoping to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE User-Name='%PERSON%'
```

but apply it to my CSV file.

```
    public static DataTable ParseCSV(string path, String pattern)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
            return null;
        string full = Path.GetFullPath(path);
        string file = Path.GetFileName(full);
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(full);
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
            + "Data Source=\"" + dir + "\\\";"
            + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited\"";
        string query = "SELECT F1, F2, F3 FROM " + file;
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);
        try
        {
            dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ioe.Message.ToString());
        }
        dAdapter.Dispose();
        return dTable;
    }


    private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        path = textBoxFilePath.Text.ToString().Trim();
        //BindingSource to sync DataTable and DataGridView
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        //set the BindingSource DataSource
        bSource.DataSource = ParseCSV(path, pattern);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
    }
```

Also my CSV file has a header row which i would like to be the header row for my DataGridView.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your select statement to:

```
query = "select F3 from " + file;
```

to retrieve the third column. If you want to add the headers then change the connection string to include HDR=YES and refer to the columns by name in the same way you would for a normal query:

```
query = "select mycolumn from " + file;
```

Comment: how do you get the WHERE clause to work or get the header row (out or into the datagridview headers)

Comment: I believe the HDR parameter tells the jet engine to treat the first row as the column names.

Comment: You could just say use something like query = "select mycolumn from " + file + " where mycolumn = 'abc'" to filter the results. Alternatively you could 'Select' from the datatable (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx)

Comment: I tried that I get 0 results. My attempted query                 string query = "SELECT [Pc-Tag], [User-Name], [Date], [Time] FROM " + file + " WHERE [User-Name] LIKE " + pattern;

Comment: The pattern I've used was *, % and actual letters like 'a' and 'A'

Comment: You'll need to have single quotes around pattern - try using " WHERE [User-Name] LIKE '%" + pattern + "%';